# SVG Drop Shadow Spread

Tags: svg, svg-filters, dropshadow

I'm trying to manipulate SVG drop shadows (to emulate material design elements).

An element in material design contains 3 drop shadows of varying values depending on what level of elevation they are at. The best solution I have found to emulate this with an SVG element is to use CSS filter's drop shadow. This, however, doesn't support spread. Does anyone know a workaround that would allow me to manipulate the spread of the shadow? The only solution I can think of is creating 3 separate elements, 1 for each shadow and scaling that actual element, which seems over the top.

Answer (score 5):

You can manipulate the spread of a shadow using feComponentTransfer/feFuncA. For example:

```
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
<feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncA type="gamma" exponent="0.5" amplitude="2"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
```

I wrote a tool mimicking Photoshop's dropshadow control outputting a valid SVG filter: you can use it (and see the source) here:http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/sJopz

Comment: I wrote a small test to see how to manipulate a filter size but I'm not sure what attributes your manipulating to do this. I'm having trouble understanding how the transfer function is working. http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/mPBVdQ?editors=1100

Comment: It's the Amplitude of the feFuncA: see here for how ti affects spread: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/RaLrXw

Comment: This seems to be altering the blur distance. I'm trying to alter the size of the shadow

Comment: Use a larger stdDeviation if you want a larger shadow - spread is a PhotoShop term that refers to the blur dropoff

Comment: I see, mdn use it to reference the size of the shadow - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: English! So imprecise!